# How to merge similar but not identical rows?

Tags: r, database, data-analysis, data-cleaning, levenshtein-distance

I have a large dataset (1 000 000+ rows) containing data regarding customers, i.e. email address, full name, country, zip code, street name, street number. We want to do some analyses regarding customer behavior, where it is crucial that we know which customers are repeat customers, and which customers are new ones.

Right now, we use only email address to identify unique customers, but we find that many people use multiple email addresses to place orders at our company. Therefore, we want to use the other customer data to try and identify customers that bought with different email addresses. The problem we run into here, is that some people write their streetnames like Baker St. , and the second time like Baker Street, or like BakerStreet, or BakerSt.

So, what I want to do is: look at email addresses in dataset. Give identical email addresses a customer. If there is no identical email address, look at full name + address. If these are comparable enough, the customer is the same customer, so give them the same ID. If not, give them a new customer ID.

What I have tried to do is concatenating like this: full name|country|zip code|street name|street number, and to then calculate the Levenshtein distance over the whole dataset, but as it is a large dataset, it takes way too long (around 1 - 2 second per customer). The solution has to be faster than this.

As an example, what I'm looking for is:

Example DF:

```
df <- data.frame(
name = c("Andrew Slang","Matthew Willemson","Peter Johnson","AndrewwSlang","Peter Johnson","PetterJohnson"), 
email = c("a.slang@gmail.com","matthew@gmail.com","peterjohnson@gmail.com","andrewslang@hotmail.com","peterjohnson@gmail.com","p.johnson@hotmail.com"),
country = c("UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK"),
zip = c("1234AB","1235AB","1236AB","1234AB","1236AB","1236AB"),
housenr = c("13","4","52","13","52","52"))
```

Example answer with added column with new customer ID based on X amount of overlap (e.g. 90% overlap):

```
df_after <- data.frame(name = c("Andrew Slang","Matthew Willemson","Peter Johnson","AndrewwSlang","Peter Johnson","PetterJohnson"),
                       email = c("a.slang@gmail.com","matthew@gmail.com","peterjohnson@gmail.com","andrewslang@hotmail.com","peterjohnson@gmail.com","p.johnson@hotmail.com"),
                       country = c("UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK"),
                       zip = c("1234AB","1235AB","1236AB","1234AB","1236AB","1236AB"),
                       housenr = c("13","4","52","13","52","52"),
                       customerID = c("1","2","3","1","3","3"))
```

Here, customerID is added, and the first and fourth row are given the same ID, and the third, fifth and sixth row.

Comment: So if the email doesn't match, you then go to name + address. What happens if there is an issue in how they wrote their address? I can't think of a way to account for a misspelled address or miswritten address

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  As I understand it, you've stumbled into one of the most difficult problems in data cleaning and there's no computationally simple solution.  I recommend taking a look at this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/d8hzz5/group_large_data_set_by_levenshtein_distance/) where they talk about several options that you might try implementing to see which is the most efficient for your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it! If anyone has some more insight on how to approach this problem, I'd love to hear it.